# Notifications stop AirPlay

Tags: iphone, ios, airplay

I play music from Amazon Music over AirPlay from iPhone 12. I stream music to a Marantz CD player which has AirPlay feature. Whenever I get a notification, the Amazon player stops. Is there a way to disable this "feature"?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you using a Mac or Apple TV or iPad or web browser or iPhone to access Amazon Music?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Wonderful edit - I'll add some tags so people that follow those topics might see your question in their preferred questions / feed.